# invoking ssh through pexpect has terminal/display issues

Tags: bash, ssh, pexpect, xterm

Have the following snippet to login to given host and execute a set of commands and then let the session be available for user.

Everything works as intended except that somehow the term display settings is messed up.

For example `ls` shows misaligned output and `vi <file>` doesn't show the file contents properly(snapshot attached)

Even when commands on the shell exceeds the current line, moving around the line doesn't work properly.

Tried different options by playing around with TERM settings but nothing works

```
import pexpect, struct, fcntl, termios, signal, sys, os
def sigwinch_passthrough (sig, data):
    s = struct.pack("HHHH", 0, 0, 0, 0)
    a = struct.unpack('hhhh', fcntl.ioctl(sys.stdout.fileno(), termios.TIOCGWINSZ , s))
    global child
    child.setwinsize(a[0],a[1])

if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
    print "Usage: sys.argv[0] <ip>"
    sys.exit(1)

ip = sys.argv[1]
ip.strip()
print "10.2.12.",ip

child = pexpect.spawn('/usr/bin/ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no em7admin@10.2.12.%s' % ip, env=os.environ)
signal.signal(signal.SIGWINCH, sigwinch_passthrough)

child.setwinsize(400,400)
child.sendline('export TERM="xterm-256color"')

child.expect('password:.*', timeout=9)
child.sendline('em7admin')

child.expect ('.*\$ ')
child.sendline('sudo bash')
child.expect('.* password for.*:.*', timeout=9)

child.sendline('em7admin')
child.expect ('.*\# ')

child.sendline('unset TMOUT')
child.interact()
```

[image]

Comment: Does it work if you don't run `sudo` on the remote system?

Comment: no..its same behavior

Comment: It seems like an issue related to the `TERM` variable. You should probably use `os.environ["TERM"]` to get the actual value and pass it along.

Comment: And window size `400 x 400` seems really large. I just created a window using the full width of my 32-inch monitor, and it's only 84 columns wide.

Comment: like this `child = pexpect.spawn('/usr/bin/ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no em7admin@10.2.12.%s' % ip, env=os.environ['TERM'])
child.sendline('export TERM="$env"')`

Comment: take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.

Comment: btw this formatting issue happens only for split sessions... and goes away if i enlarge the session and restore to original size